# visual studio code 400 bad request

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code

I have a sample .NET Core 2.0 WebApi  code, which works in Visual Studio 2017, but the same code does not work in Visual Code 1.18.
The POST command comes back with 400 Bad Request. The GET command works in both.
I am must be missing some file or setting that's it's done for you in Visual Studio 2017.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in Visual Studio Code?

Thank You 
Peter

Here's the code for the controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TodoApi.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TodoContext _context;

        public TodoController(TodoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

            if (_context.TodoItems.Count() != 0) return;
            _context.TodoItems.Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.TodoItems.ToList();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            TodoItem item = _context.TodoItems.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] TodoItem item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Update(long id, [FromBody] TodoItem item)
        {
            if (item == null || item.Id != id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            TodoItem todo = _context.TodoItems.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (todo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            todo.IsComplete = item.IsComplete;
            todo.Name = item.Name;

            _context.TodoItems.Update(todo);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return new NoContentResult();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Delete(long id)
        {
            TodoItem todo = _context.TodoItems.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (todo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.TodoItems.Remove(todo);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return new NoContentResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you put a breakpoint inside the POST method, and debug through it, what happens?

Comment: How is Visual Studio Code running your application? IIS, IIS Express, or HttpSys?  Also, sometimes to run in IIS or HttpSys you have to elevate to Administrator, if it is running within Code.

Comment: How are you sending the POST command? From Postman? Chrome? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to everyone for wasting their time!

For Visual Studio Code I did not have anything in the Body while using Postman and of course [FormBody] parameter was null and that's why I got Bad Request message.